# Fill a form field with initial values from another model (which is a foreign key)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have 2 models, Company and Post.

```
class Post(Meta):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_description = models.TextField(max_length=800)
```

What I need:

1) When a user create a post, `the company` FK will be set thru code
2) Also at form initialization the field `company_description`, will be prepopulated from the Company model, field `description`(not the same name)
3) On save if the user doesn't modify anything to the field, the initial value will be save

1,2,3 only on creation.

I checked [Django documentation regarding initialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) 
but their example, is more simple they just get some data/text, in my case I first need to set FK, than get description from the FK Model, so not just text.

The pk/slug of the company I can get from url or from request thru multiple calls request.user.acc.company

```
path('<int:pk>/post/add/', CompanyPostCreateView.as_view(), name='create')
```

and in the view:

```
 company_pk = kwargs.get('pk')
```

and overwrite the `form_valid`, but here is the issue, `form_valid` is called on validation, and I want to show this info before validation on form initialization, and I don't know how.

Comment: You need to give more details and show the view so far. When you say the FK will be set "through code", how and where is that happening?

Comment: @DanielRoseman,  I added more info, in this case I don't know exactly where  I can get the FK, because is on validation is too late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by overwriting get_form_kwargs

```
 def get_form_kwargs(self):
        self.company = Company.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['initial']['company_description'] = self.company.description
        return kwargs
```

I use self.company to pass later to a different method, not redo the query.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything particularly complicated about this. You can get the FK at the start of the view and use it in the initial dictionary:

```
company = Company.objects.get(pk=company_pk)
form = PostForm(intial={'company_description': company.description})
```

**Edit** With a CreateView, you could just override `get_initial`:

```
def get_initial(self):
    company = Company.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return {'company_description': company.description}
```

Comment: I use a CreateView with formclass

Comment: Well, that's why I asked to see the full view. But see my update.

Comment: @Danile Roseman  I didn't had a View (beside de default generic createview),; I found a solution and I think is ok, at least is working